# C define const global using extern

Tags: c, declaration, definition, extern, linkage

I have 2 files, one containing a global const variable and the other containing an extern definition of the variable, does this work, when i compile the files seperately and link the files together?

```
/* File 1 */
const int itest;
```

```
/* File 2 */
extern const int itest = 123;
```

Comment: That *may* work (most likely will, but you may get warnings) but it would be more consistent if you had the `extern` keyword in the other place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A proper way to define a variable in one source file and to make it available by name in others is to define it in one source file with:

```
const int itest = 123;  // "extern" is optional and is traditionally omitted in a definition.
```

and to declare it in any source file(s) that use it with:

```
extern const int itest; // "extern" should be used here.
```

General practice is to put the above declaration in a header file and include that header file in any file that uses the variable, including the one that defines it. Reusing one declaration from a header file helps avoid errors in retyping, pasting, or editing. Including the header in the source file that defines the variable allows the compiler to see both during the same compilation and check them for consistency.

For reasons related to the history of C development and use, `const int itest;` without `extern` or an initializer is a special thing called a *tentative definition*. This is not a definition but can cause a definition to be created, in effect. Some build tools treat definitions created by tentative definitions specially, allowing them to coalesce with other definitions. This means that having `const int itest;` in one source file and `extern const int itest = 123;` might or might not generate a linker error, depending on the build tools used and the switches used with them. You usually do not want this feature and should avoid tentative definitions.

Answer (score -1):

These both declarations with external linkage

```
const int itest;
```

and

```
extern const int itest = 123;
```

are definitions (the first one is a tentative definition; the constant is initialized by zero). So the object with the same name `itest` with external linkage is defined twice.

Instead you should write in one file

```
const int itest = 123;
```

and in another file

```
extern const int itest;
```

The last one is a declaration but not a definition because does not have an initializer.

On the other hand, you could declare the constant with internal linkage and place its declaration in a header like

```
static const int itest = 123;
```

Comment: `const int test` is a *tentative definition*, not a definition by itself, and how it is treated in this case depends on the build tools.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The tentative definition is a definition.

Comment: Actually, no, Vlad, a tentative definition *is not* a definition, because there can be more than one for the same identifier in the same translation unit.  Also because the specification says "If a translation unit contains one or more tentative definitions for an identifier, and the translation unit contains no external definition for that identifier, [...]".  That would not make sense (could never be satisfied) if tentative definitions were definitions.

Comment: @JohnBollinger There is written clear "then
the behavior is exactly as if the translation unit contains a file scope declaration of that
identifier, with the composite type as of the end of the translation unit, with an initializer
equal to 0." It is a definition. But it is a tentative definition because as if the definition is placed in the end of the translation unit. Thus the linker will get two translation units with two definitions of an object with the same name. Otherwise the C Standard selected another name in the term instead of the word definition.

Comment: No, @Vlad.  A tentative definition ensures that the TU will be interpreted *as if there were* a definition in the event that there in fact isn't one, but a tentative definition is not itself a definition.

Comment: @JohnBollinger It is a definition. The compiler creates an external name with an initializer. And all this is written in the section "6.9.2 External object definitions". In other words there is "explicit" definition and there is tentative definition with the help of the compiler. The compiler creates the definition. Your program can consist from one translation unit with a tentative definition and your object code after translation will have this definition.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Tentative definition means that it is a tentative definition in one translation unit irrelative to other translation units whether they define such a name or not. The compiler does not know how many translation units the program has. So it must to build the definition in the object file.

Comment: As John Bollinger has noted, although a tentative definition **causes** a definition to exist in effect, later, it itself **is not** a definition. And this matters. `const int itest; const int itest;` is not two definitions and therefore does not violate the standard’s rule about multiple definitions. It is two tentative definitions, which ultimately cause only one definition to exist in effect.

Comment: Further, some build tools treat tentative definitions differently from definitions; `const int test;` in one translation unit and `extern const int itest = 123;` in another translation unit will result in a single definition. This is allowed by the C standard because it does not define the behavior if there are two definitions to start with—the build tools step in to define the behavior; they were deliberately designed and documented to do this. And that is important for askers/readers to know so they can understand why they might not get a link error for this.

Comment: @EricPostpischil If these declarations appeared in one translation unit then there is no problem because the compiler in the end of the translation unit generate in the object file the definition that corresponds to the const int itest = 0;. The object file will contain this definition. One more the compiler knows nothing about how many translation units the program has. It can contain only one translation unit. It is the compiler that generates object code. So it must provide the definition.

Comment: That is not responsive to the fact that a tentative definition is not a definition. It is consistent with the stated fact that a tentative definition **causes** a definition, but it is not a definition itself, so it does not disprove anything John Bollinger and I have stated.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The compiler simply omits its definition to the end of the translation unit. For example you can declare an incomplete array and change its single element in the translation unit. If you will define the same array as a complete type in other translation unit you will get two different definitions of the same array.